# Mutt attachment_menu order - First attachments then the messages

Tags: mutt

While seeing the attachments of a message (attachment menu), I always have the message(s) ("I" inline) and only after the attachments (A) - See the screenshot. How could I invert this order or even hide the I ones?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: An ugly way to jump straight to the first attachment is a macro in muttrc:  " macro index V "<view-attachments><collapse-parts><search>A<enter>"    "